# Imageview leaves the padding in launch screen in xcode 9.2 ios

Tags: ios, iphone, splash-screen, launch-screen

[image: this is my image with constraint]I want to make an application which has splash image of full screen size.App should be compatible to all the device from iphone 5 to iphone 10.but when i add image in launchscreen.storyboardit leaves the space from right left and bottom.how to add full screen image to launchscreen.storyboard ? if image view is added in launchscreen and image is added .Content mode is also scaletofill still its not working.
i have used assets also but wont achieve it?
pls help with the answers.thanx in advance

Comment: are you sure your image is properly generated? i think your image has white spaces

Comment: No it wont have white spaces.it is properly generated

Comment: can you show your view hierarchy? content mode of your image view is "Scale To Fit" i guess right?

Comment: thanx it is solved actually two views are overlapped and due to it white space is shown ....thank you so much...@PratikJamariya

Comment: you're welcome 

Answer (score 2):

I think, when you are setting the constraints of imageView in LaunchScreen.storyboard, constraints to margin is checked.

try setting the constraints of your imageview, while keeping the **constraints of margin unchecked**. It will make your image go fullscreen.

Hope it helps :)

[image]

Comment: Done this but not fruitful.check the screenshot attached juss now

Comment: try using the content mode as "aspect Fill" 

If the issue still persists, then i think u should change the image and check again.

Comment: Thank....It's done...Actually the two views are overlapped which cause the white spaces....Than @madhur Diwan

Comment: ohky... happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

While adding top and bottom constrain, Select View instead of Safe Area.

[image]